# How to assign shortcuts to FileMerge

Tags: macos, diff, nib, filemerge

I know you can assign shortcuts by editing the nib file that FileMerge uses, but I have no idea how to do it.

I want to replace the "choose left" and "choose right" actions with specific keys on my keyboard (for example, left key and right key). How can I do that?

Answer (score 12):

Although not published, there are shortcuts already in place. Left arrow chooses the left file change, right arrow chooses the right file change, and up and down navigate to the previous/next file change.

Comment: This post does not answer the OP's question, i.e. how to modify and add shortcut keys. Would be great in particular to add shortcut keys for the "choose both (left first)", "choose first (right first)" and "choose neither" actions.

Comment: Another useful existing shortcut is "Cmd+D" to go to the next conflict

Comment: Still not enough shortcuts, I'm afraid. There are more actions (choose neither, choose both left/right first) and it would be very useful if there were shortcuts for them. Clicking with mouse is slow (and feels unprofessional:)).